# Can't configure IntelliJ for Android

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea, android-sdk-tools

I have my JDK configured to my IntelliJ fine. I downloaded and re-downloaded the Android SDK and downloaded all the API's from the SDK Manager just fine also. It's when I configure my IntelliJ to my Android SDK folder, my IntelliJ says it's configured. The only API I have access to from my API drop-down is Android 4.4, I'm not sure what happened to all the other API's. Then when the project is displayed. I get the error message below. I'm exhausted, I suck, just please give me a solution to how I could configure IntelliJ so I could get on with my Android life.

> ### Console Error:
>
> The project wasn't generated by 'android' tool.
>
> Error: Error parsing the sdk.
>
> Error: Failed to create C:\Program Files\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030\sdk\add-ons.
>
> Error: Unable to parse SDK content.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on your program shortcut and select Run As Administrator

or alternatively create the directories in the message manually e.g. add-ons folder